# ProgressBar like in Miui 13

Tags: android, user-interface, progress-bar, user-experience, android-progressbar

how to make a progressbar like in miui 13 to simulate water and move according to the accelerometer of the smartphone, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24vXE.jpg)

I tried in different ways but I can't get the result I need, I would like to get a beautiful and smooth animation.

Comment: I think you'll want to create a custom ProgressBar for that